Question about joint limits
Let $f:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a function defined as $f(n,m) = G(x_n,X_m)$, where $x_n$ converges to $x$ and $X_m$ is a sequence or random variables that converges in distribution to $X$. We know about $G$ that $\lim\sup_n G(x_n,X_m)\leq G(x,X_m)$ for every $m\in\mathbb N$.Besides that, we know that $\lim_m G(x_n,X_m) = G(x_n,X)$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. I do not know how to prove that $\lim\sup_n G(x_n,X_n) = G(x,X)$. I think that it is a question of notation, but maybe there are something more...
It is clear, by hypohtesis, that $G(\cdot;X_m)$ is upper semicontinuous and $G(x_n,\cdot)$ is continuous.
Thank you in advance.

What are you assuming  about the function $G$?

$G(.,X_m)$ is upper semicontinuous for every $m$ and $G(x_n,X_m)$ is continuous for every $n$

Edit you question to include this new info.
